# Need help creating a web socket connection with socket.io

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js and when I try to open a new web socket connection I get this following error on my terminal

```
.use(serveStatic('public').listen(3000));
                               ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I can't understand why it saying that.

Any help would be really appreciated. Below is the code I am using. Thanks!

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
    io = require('socket.io');

var app = connect()
    .use(serveStatic('public').listen(3000));

var socket = io.listen(app);
```

Answer (score 2):

The closing parentheses are in the wrong place:

```
var app = connect().use(serveStatic('public')).listen(3000);
                                             ^ this is the correct location
```

Also, strictly speaking, the return value of `.listen()` is a `Server` instance, not a (Connect) app instance. To prevent confusion, I would suggest using separate variables:

```
var app    = connect();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var socket = io.listen(server);

app.use(serveStatic('public'));
```